# Django no referer CSRF error only on iPhone

Tags: iphone, django, nginx

I have a Django 2.2/nginx/uwsgi web-site (https://rodichi.net), which works fine on Windows, MacOS, Android, on all browsers—but not on iPhone. The browser doesn't matter. The error I get is "no referer". I am stuck. In attempt to debug, `csrf_failure(request, reason)` sends an email to me each time a CSRF error view is shown. It looks like this

```
Username: AnonymousUser
Reason: Referer checking failed - no Referer.
Request: POST: <QueryDict: {'password': ['xxxx'], 'username': ['test_user'], 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['F8CI6gqc3HIXx8eVwa4cO9HrrNRh8ObwfaVfxPdBrpKQPu83Jk1KvLQwnRpm0dSl'], 'next': ['']}>
```

I don't have any experience with iPhone myself (using BrowserStack to reproduce the behaviour). Is it an expected situation? I cannot find anything like that on the internet, which puzzles me. Please comment if more info is needed from my side to narrow down the problem.

UPDATE: 
I just rechecked with BrowserStack and now the site actually works on iPhone 6S (Chrome and Safari) but not on iPhone 6S plus (both Chrome and Safari). It doesn't get more clear. Perhaps it was always like that, I just didn't expect different behaviour on different models.

Comment: Can you post the actual error?

Comment: You're using JS to redirect? How are you doing it?

Comment: @IainShelvington, which redirect do you mean? The error appears on the very first login POST, when a user is trying to send username/password. Added error details too.